Slack webhook being sent with noticeable delay?
We are developing a Slack application which is getting webhooks from Slack. Most of the time everything works fine, but from time to time we see a message coming with noticeable delay - like a few minutes later than it was actually sent.
On the screenshot the top line shows that the message was received at 11:30, but the "ts" field (which is Slack's internal field saying when the message was sent) contains 11:24 - so basically 6 minutes delay from sending a message to receiving webhook. Is there anyone who faced the same issue before?

